# Compile - Problematics - Latex with TexShop

Tags: cv, resume

I don't know why I can't compile my Curriculum Vitae from LaTex. I would get something that looks like [this website](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-graduate-cv). Does anyone could help me at this level? You can even modify it to make it more live content to the person reading my C.V.

```
\documentclass[margin, 10pt]{res}

\usepackage{helvet}

\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in}



\begin{document}

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf John Smith} 

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 1pt}\smallskip 

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{xxxxxxx} 
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{xxxxxxx}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{xxxxxxx}


\begin{resume}

\section{Academic formation}

- Actual study :  2nd year in Pure Mathematics at UdeM

- Previous studies :  natural science (pure profile) at College de Valleyfield, Cegep of Saint-Hyacinthe in management and farm business operations (FMT) and high school diploma.

\section{Research intership}

I have no research experience with a teacher. However, here are some mathematical books I read, flew: \\

\begin{itemize}
\item Differential topology, Victor Guillemin and Alan Pollack
\item Topology : point-set and geometric, Paul L. Shick 
\item Differential geometry of curves and surfaces, Manfredo P. do Carmo 
\end{itemize}


\section{-1.5 cm} {Experience related to mathematics}

\begin{itemize}
\item Putnam contest 2015 
\item Putnam contest 2014 (Result : 20/120) 
\item Contest - Quebec Mathematical Association (2013)
\end{itemize}

\section{Work experience - Without mathematics}

1- During my time at Collège de Valleyfield \\ \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Committee member of the scientific journal 
\item Tutor Assistance center in French (written)
\item Tutor in English 
\item Participation to '' contest philosophize '' 
\end{itemize}

2- June 2013 - January 2014 \\ \\
Laboratory technician - Pharmacy Bélanger and Gauthier (Brunet) 
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Assist the pharmacist and reached a maximum of technical tasks 
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork, organization and a lot of initiative 
\end{itemize}

3- June 2012 - Febuary 2013 \\ \\
Laboratory technician - Pharmacy Chicha and Lafontaine (HEA) \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Assist the pharmacist and reached a maximum of technical tasks 
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork, organization and a lot of initiative 
\end{itemize}

4- March 2011- April 2012 \\ \\
Responsable clerk - Jean Coutu pharmacy \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Personnel management, product placement, checkout and cleaning 
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork, organization, initiative and leadership 
\end{itemize}

5- Winter 2010 -2011 \\ \\
Factory Worker - Sika Canada \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Caning, packaging and cleaning 
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork and assiduity 
\end{itemize}

6- Summer 2009-2010 \\ \\
Farm Worker - Internship Saskatchewan and New Brunswick \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Field work (harvesting, seed work, tillage) and maintenance 
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork, meticulous organization, initiative, autonomy and adaptation
\end{itemize} 

7- 2003 - 2011 \\ \\
Farm Worker - Agri-Fusion 2000 Inc.\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Work requested: Maintenance of a drying plan, field work (harvesting, seed, tillage) and maintenance
\item Qualifications: Good teamwork, meticulous organization, initiative, autonomy, adaptation and ability to communicate 
\end{itemize}

\section{Soft Skills} 

\begin{itemize}
\item Mathematica 
\item Matlab 
\item LaTex 
\item Word 
\item Excel 
\item Powerpoint  
\end{itemize}

   \end{resume}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to have res.cls at a place your `latex` can find, e.g. in the same directory as your .tex file

Comment: I am not use to with LaTex. How may I get this ''file''? It is not clear for me how to do it.

Comment: It's available at the the website you linked, under Download Template (as zip)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments